# lein repl fails due to authentication behind corporate proxy (windows 7)

Tags: windows, authentication, clojure, proxy, leiningen

I am having issues with proxy authentication when running `lein repl`.
I am using

```
> lein --version
    Leiningen 2.8.1 on Java 1.8.0_181 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

on Windows 7 64 bit. I have set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables.
I installed via

```
> lein self-install
```

from powershell. This had problems with proxy authentication as well, but I was abled to solve the issue by adapting the call to powershell in the script (use `$client.Proxy.Credentials = Get-Credential`, and adjusting SecurityProtocolType).

When I try to run `lein repl` I get

```
PS> lein repl
nREPL server started on port 54104 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:54104
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: reply:reply:jar:0.3.7, org.thnetos:cd-client:jar:0.3.6, clj-http-lite:clj-http-lite:jar:0.2.0, cheshire:cheshire:jar:4.0.3, clj-stacktrace:clj-stacktrace:jar:0.2.7, com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6, clj-http:clj-http:jar:0.3.6,
:0.3.7 from/to clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:393)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (:-2)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (:-1)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (:-1)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (:-1)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:93)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod (Reflector.java:28)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies_STAR_.invokeStatic (aether.clj:806)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies_STAR_.doInvoke (aether.clj:707)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies.invokeStatic (aether.clj:815)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies.doInvoke (aether.clj:809)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    cemerick.pomegranate$add_dependencies.invokeStatic (pomegranate.clj:83)
    cemerick.pomegranate$add_dependencies.doInvoke (pomegranate.clj:57)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:457)
    leiningen.repl$client.invokeStatic (repl.clj:261)
    leiningen.repl$client.invoke (repl.clj:258)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invokeStatic (repl.clj:320)
    leiningen.repl$repl.doInvoke (repl.clj:267)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invokeStatic (repl.clj:307)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invoke (repl.clj:267)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:379)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:648)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__4667.doInvoke (main.clj:284)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:410)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:29)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:648)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic (main.clj:334)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke (main.clj:320)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic (main.clj:340)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke (main.clj:336)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__4734.invoke (main.clj:420)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:411)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:408)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:408)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:379)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:314)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:310)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:421)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:384)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:436)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:388)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:160)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: reply:reply:jar:0.3.7, org.thnetos:cd-client:jar:0.3.6, clj-http-lite:clj-http-lite:jar:0.2.0, cheshire:cheshire:jar:4.0.3, clj-stacktrace:clj-stacktrace:jar:0.2.7, com.cemerick:drawbridge:jar:0.0.6, clj-http:clj-http:ja
reply:jar:0.3.7 from/to clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:453)
    org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:255)
    org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:376)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (:-2)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (:-1)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (:-1)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (:-1)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:93)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod (Reflector.java:28)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies_STAR_.invokeStatic (aether.clj:806)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies_STAR_.doInvoke (aether.clj:707)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies.invokeStatic (aether.clj:815)
    cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies.doInvoke (aether.clj:809)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    cemerick.pomegranate$add_dependencies.invokeStatic (pomegranate.clj:83)
    cemerick.pomegranate$add_dependencies.doInvoke (pomegranate.clj:57)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:457)
    leiningen.repl$client.invokeStatic (repl.clj:261)
    leiningen.repl$client.invoke (repl.clj:258)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invokeStatic (repl.clj:320)
    leiningen.repl$repl.doInvoke (repl.clj:267)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invokeStatic (repl.clj:307)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invoke (repl.clj:267)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:379)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:648)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__4667.doInvoke (main.clj:284)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:410)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:29)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:648)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:641)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic (main.clj:334)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke (main.clj:320)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic (main.clj:340)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke (main.clj:336)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__4734.invoke (main.clj:420)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:411)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:408)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:408)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:379)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:646)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:314)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:310)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:421)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:384)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:436)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:388)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:160)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:700)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact reply:reply:jar:0.3.7 from/to clojars (https://repo.clojars.org/): Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.
 at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed (ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
    org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
    org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:76)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (:-1)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (:-1)
    java.lang.Thread.run (:-1)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.
 at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1011)
    org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:962)
    org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:569)
    org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:436)
    org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:413)
    org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
    org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:359)
    org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:76)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (:-1)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (:-1)
    java.lang.Thread.run (:-1)
```

I am out of ideas how to set the proxy authentication.

EDIT:
I tried adding the proxy parameters to the java call with `-Dhttp.proxyHost=myHost -Dhttp.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttp.proxyUser=myUser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=myPw` these parameters seem to not be used/have no effect.
The corresponding parameters work with e.g. visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variables should work with `lein repl`. Did you prefix the `http_proxy` with http? Or the `https_proxy` with https? Or try:

```
set http_proxy=proxy_ip:port
set http_proxy_user=user
set http_proxy_pass=password
```

Comment: i have set the environment variables in the form `http://user:pass@proxy:port`. I tried with and without the http. I tried doing set in powershell to no effect.

Comment: Additional remark: It seems that lein is not using the http_proxy variable directly (see bash script) but instead depends on `[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials` being the right thing. Which seems not to be the case here.

Comment: Okay. There probably is a bug in lein then. You can also try adding the proxy to the Maven settings. Not sure if it works. See https://sookocheff.com/post/clojure/using-leiningen-behind-a-windows-proxy/

Comment: And another idea is to add the settings to the leiningen profile. To configure the `:user` profile, open up or create the `~/.lein/profiles.clj` and enter something like the following:

`{:user {:jvm-opts ["-Dhttp.proxyHost=165.226.204.104" "-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080" <and add user and password>]}}`. 
 See http://blog.twonegatives.com/post/24613573053/how-to-set-leiningen2s-proxy.

Comment: And note that you have to reinstall Leiningen after setting the environment variables. See http://www.bite-code.com/2013/10/18/installing-leiningen-behind-a-proxy/.

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by "Leiningen is honoring these variables" since even `lein self-install` fails if I don't modify the script. `$client.Proxy.Credentials =[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials` results in empty settings. This may well be specific to the environment here. Thanks for the infos btw. I already followed all the linked posts to no avail.

Comment: Hmm okay. Maybe contact an administrator at your work place.

Answer (score 0):

Set also env variable **https**_proxy=proxy_ip:port additionally to http_proxy